# C# field updated

Tags: c#, object

I'm developing a fairly big project and I'm not sure is the current architecture is up to the task. We have a objects like this:

```
public class Order()
{
    public int id;
    public int TotalProductsWeight { get; private set;}
    public IList<Products> prodList = new List<Products>() { get; private set;}

    public void AddProducts(IList<Products> prod)
    {
        prodList.AddRange(prod);

        foreach(var e in prodList)
             //Doing complex stuff and put the result in TotalProductWeight
    }
}
```

There is a field `TotalProductsWeight` which is expensive to calculate so we update it only when adding a new product. The problem is this object is saved to a database and when we read it from the same db we'd like to load also the `TotalProductsweight` stored previusly.

The only solution i'm thinking of is calling a method that updates the TotalProductsWeight ignoring the value on the db.

[EDIT]
The question is: Is there a bettere way to store a result of a complex computation inside an object so we don't need to recalculate it every time and at the same time loading a values in that field only when reading from a database withouth exposing the field in the rest of the code?

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: I would hedge a bet that computing the `TotalProductWeight` would not be too much for a machine to handle. Without looking at the computation it is hard to tell.

Comment: @Simon TotalWeight is a stupid example the complexity of the real computetion is quadratic

Comment: If it is derived from the other data, why is it stored in the database? Can't you just not load it from the database, but trigger a recomputation when the remaining fields have been loaded?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper eh that is a good question. Because we need to run queries using that field and we have 10.000+ rows so recalucalitng it on the fly is not an option

Comment: If you are already persisting the Order object to the database why is there an issue? Just retrieve the full Order from the DB when needed and write back the full Order (including TotalProductWeight) when persisting the object. The calculation is within your business logic, so as long as the Weight is being recalculated when the ProductsList is updated, I don't see an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like something that's easily handled by lazy evaluation. Consider something like this:

```
public class Order()
{
    public int id;

    // Cached total weight.
    private int _totalProductsWeight;

    // When true, must compute weight before returning
    private bool _dirtyFlag;

    public int TotalProductsWeight 
    { 
       get
       {
           if (_dirtyFlag)
           {
               _totalProductsWeight = ComputeWeight();
               _dirtyFlag = false;
           }
           return _totalProductsWeight;
       }
    }

    public IList<Products> prodList = new List<Products>() { get; private set;}

    public void AddProducts(IList<Products> prod)
    {
        prodList.AddRange(prod);

        // Mark the weight as dirty.
        _dirtyFlag = true;
    }
}
```

Now, you only compute the total weight when you need to. So you could add a hundred items to the products list and never have to compute the weight until the first time somebody asks for it.

For storing in the database, you can store the weight if you like, and when you load from the database just set the dirty flag to false. If you don't want to store the total weight, then make sure to set the dirty flag to true when you load the object's data. That way it will compute the weight the first time somebody asks for it.

Also, if this information is stored in a database, there's always the risk of somebody deleting a product from the database and not updating the total weight. In which case, if you persist the total weight and read it back, your data is not consistent. It's up to you to decide if that's a real risk that you should guard against. If you think it can happen, then you probably shouldn't persist the total weight field, but rather recompute it on load (or the first time it's queried).

Note that when you do this, the only code that should access the `_totalProductsWeight` field is the get accessor and the code that writes it to the database and reads it back. If any other code reads `_totalProductsWeight`, you run the risk of reading an old value. (Not that I've ever made that mistake, mind you ... *cough*)